# How do I find the largest int in a std::set<int>?

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

I have a `std::set<int>`, what's the proper way to find the largest int in this set?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

What comparator are you using?

For the default this will work:

```
if(!myset.empty())
    *myset.rbegin();
else
    //the set is empty
```

This will also be constant time instead of linear like the max_element solution.

Comment: Finding the max element is constant time, yes, but populating the set is not, since it's sorting at insert. A unordered_set has constant time insert, but would require a search for the maximum element.

Comment: But since the original question starts with "I have a std::set", we can assume that non-constant insertion time is going to be incurred regardless of our searching mechanism.  Since you've already paid the price, why not take advantage of it by using a constant-time search method?

Comment: @crunchdog: `unordered_set` only has constant time average-case, but has linear time worst-case, which is worse than `set`

Comment: FYI `*myset.begin()` gives you the minimum element

Answer (score 34):

Sets are always ordered.  Assuming you are using the default comparison (less), just grab the last element in the set.  rbegin() might be useful.

Comment: C++ standard order guarantee: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8833938/895245

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for [`std::max_element`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/max_element):

> The `max_element()` function returns an
>   iterator to the largest element in the
>   range [start,end).

Comment: This seems like the slow way to do it, since max_element can't know that the range is sorted.

Comment: This is what I get for answering a question outside my comfort zone :) I didn't know that an `std::set` was sorted by default.  Since I assumed that it was not sorted an O(n) algorithm seemed to be the only practical choice.  Now knowing what I know, yes this answer is not optimal.

Answer (score 5):

Since set sorts the element in ascending order by default, just pick up the last element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!myset.empty())
    *myset.rend();
else
    //the set is empty
```

In an ordered integer set, the last element is the largest one.

Comment: This is incorrect as `end()`/`rend()` point past the last element.

Answer (score -5):

Before you `push()` in your `set<int>` save the value in `int max` in global variable

Comment: please explain what your answer is supposed to do, and maybe provide a code example? I'm curious to see what you come up with!