# Is the std::set iteration order always ascending according to the C++ specification?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/ I read that std::set in C++ is "typically" implemented as a tree (red-black one?) and it is sorted.

I could not understand, does it mean that **by specification** iteration order of set is always ascending? Or is it only "usual implementation detail" and sometimes, some library/compiler may violate this convention?

Comment: You can also just store the negative of the numbers in the set and this way you can undo the negative once you access the element. SO basically descending order.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Per the C++ standard, iteration over the elements in an `std::set` proceeds in sorted order as determined by `std::less` or by the optional comparison predicate template argument.

(Also per the C++ standard, insertion, lookup and deletion take at most O(lg *n*) time, so balanced search trees are currently the only viable implementation choice for `std::set`, even though the use of red-black trees is not mandated by the standard.)

Comment: And even for sufficiently small collections where complexity is meaningless, stability of iterators implies that using indexes into a sorted array wouldn't possibly work.

Answer (score 34):

It means that internally `std::set` will store its elements as a sorted tree. However, the specification says nothing about the sort order. By default, `std::set` uses `std::less` and so will order from low to high. However, you can make the sorting function be whatever you want, using this template parameter:

```
std::set<valueType, comparissonStruct> myCustomOrderedSet;
```

So for example:

```
std::set<int, std::greater<int> > myInverseSortedSet;
```

or

```
struct cmpStruct {
  bool operator() (int const & lhs, int const & rhs) const
  {
    return lhs > rhs;
  }
};

std::set<int, cmpStruct > myInverseSortedSet;
```

In fact, these examples are also provided on the website you linked. More specifically here: [set constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/set/).

Answer (score 6):

> by specification iteration order of set is always ascending

Yes, the values of set are always ascending if you print them out in sequence. As the description says, it's typically implemented using Red-Black Tree(RBT), but the compiler writers have the option to violate this, but usually the would stick to the Theme of RBT since any other implementation won't be resource efficient to achieve the task of `set`.

Answer (score 5):

**C++11 N3337 standard draft**

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

23.2.4 "Associative containers" says:

> 1 Associative containers provide fast retrieval of data based on keys. The library provides four basic kinds of
>   associative containers: set, multiset, map and multimap.

and:

> 10 The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they iterate through the containers
>   in the non-descending order of keys where non-descending is defined by the comparison that was used to
>   construct them.

so **yes**, order is guaranteed by the C++ standard.

This is why gcc 6.4.0 for example implements it as a BST instead of hashmap: [What is the underlying data structure of a STL set in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558153/what-is-the-underlying-data-structure-of-a-stl-set-in-c/51944661#51944661)

Contrast this with C++11 `unordered_set`, which tends to provide better performance with a hashmap implementation, at the cost of being more restricted (no free sorted traversal) as shown at:

- [What is the underlying data structure of a STL set in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558153/what-is-the-underlying-data-structure-of-a-stl-set-in-c/51944661#51944661)
- [Why would anyone use set instead of unordered_set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349734/why-on-earth-would-anyone-use-set-instead-of-unordered-set) e.g. using a hash set.

Comment: the question is about sets

Comment: @NikolayDimitrov but doesn't my answer talk about sets, which are associative containers as shown in the first quote?

Comment: Sets are iterated in order though, that’s the main thing here. For example, maps are not

Comment: @NikolayDimitrov from my understanding of the standard and from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648756/is-the-order-of-iterating-through-stdmap-known-and-guaranteed-by-the-standard both seem to be iterated in order.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant unordered_map which is an actual hash map

Answer (score 4):

The default comparator is less, so the set will be ordered ascending. To change this you can specify another existing or custom comparator as a template argument.