# Change the order of a std::set as a member attribute

Tags: c++

I am trying to change the order of a set in a particular configuration :

a customObject has the following form

```
class CustomObject{
public:

...
std::set<CustomObject*> container;

};
```

and I would like to keep permanently the property telling that the container is sorted in the following order :

`elt1` & `elt2` are elements of container, 
and 
`elt1 < elt2` iff `elt1.container.size()<elt2.container.size()`

I know I have to use

```
struct cmpStruct {
    bool operator() (int const & lhs, int const & rhs) const
  {
    return lhs > rhs;
  }
};
```

as described [Is the std::set iteration order always ascending according to the C++ specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833938/is-the-stdset-iteration-order-always-ascending-according-to-the-c-specificat)

But I don't know how to do to access the "this" inside the structure

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: what `this` do you want to access? I guess you want to compare two `CustomObject`s instead of `int`s. Once you change the signature of your `cmpStruct` I think you will know the answer yourself (tbh I dont understand the question at all)

Comment: How is comparing two `int`s related to your class `CustomObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
class CustomObject{
public:
    CustomObject(int _x) : x(_x) {};
    int x;
};

struct cmpStruct {
    bool operator() (const CustomObject*  lhs, const CustomObject*  rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->x > rhs->x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::set<CustomObject*, cmpStruct> container;

    CustomObject a(10);
    CustomObject b(20);
    CustomObject c(5);

    container.insert(&a);
    container.insert(&b);
    container.insert(&c);

    for(auto co : container) {
        std::cout << co->x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20
10
5
```

Comment: i know it is difficult to understand the question, but as I understood OP has a container of `CustomObject`s and wants to sort them according to their `container`s size (ie `lhs->container.size() > rhs->container.size()`)

Comment: I am not sure of what the line CustomObject(int _x) : x(_x) {}; does 
but yes, tobi303 expressed it right, I want to sort by container.size(). 

your answer is right if we add this little change, 

thanks to both of you