# Vector of set insert elements

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdlist, stdset

I'm trying to write a function which will return vector of set type string which represent members of teams.

A group of names should be classified into teams for a game. Teams should be the same size, but this is not always possible unless n is exactly divisible by k. Therefore, they decided that the first mode (n, k) teams have n / k + 1 members, and the remaining teams have n / k members.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <list>
typedef std::vector<std::set<std::string>>vek;
vek Distribution(std::vector<std::string>names, int k) {
  int n = names.size();
  vek teams(k);
  int number_of_first = n % k;
  int number_of_members_first = n / k + 1;
  int number_of_members_remaining = n / k;
  int l = 0;
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    if (i <= number_of_first) {
      int number_of_members_in_team = 0;
      while (number_of_members_in_team < number_of_members_first) {
        teams[l].insert(names[j]);
        number_of_members_in_team++;
        j++;
      }
    }
    else {
      int number_of_members_in_team = 0;
      while (number_of_members_in_team < number_of_members_remaining) {
        teams[l].insert(names[j]);
        number_of_members_in_team++;
        j++;
      }
    }
    l++;
  }

  return teams;
}

int main ()
{
  for (auto i : Distribution({"Damir", "Ana", "Muhamed", "Marko", "Ivan",
                              "Mirsad", "Nikolina", "Alen", "Jasmina", "Merima"
                             }, 3)) {
    for (auto j : i)
      std::cout << j << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> OUTPUT should be:
>
> Damir Ana Muhamed Marko
>
> Ivan Mirsad Nikolina
>
> Alen Jasmina Merima

> MY OUTPUT:
>
> Ana Damir Marko Muhamed
>
> Ivan Mirsad Nikolina
>
> Alen Jasmina Merima

Could you explain me why names are not printed in the right order?

Comment: For this case, it may help to define what a list of strings, a set of lists, and a vector of sets are, giving each of them a name and a struct/class type; then implement the add/remove/size/... methods for each of those classes. You may feel like writing a lot of boilerplate code, but it should simplify the rest of your program.

Comment: The set and the list seem to be doing the same thing: define a team. Is a team a set with one list containing 3-4 names? Or a set with 3-4 lists containing one name each? Or a set of 2 lists containing 1-2 names?

Comment: `teams[l]` is invalid because `teams` at this (or any other) point has no elements.

Comment: thank you very much, now it works, but with wrong output

Comment: Now it works fine, but names are not printed in the right order. Could you have a look?

Comment: @cpp_mountain next time please don't change the question after you have some valid answers. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`teams` being a [**`std::vector<...>`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) supports random access via an index.
`auto & team_i = teams[i];` (0 <= i < teams.size()), will give you an element of the vector. `team_i` is a reference to type `std::set<std::list<std::string>>`.

As a [**`std::set<...>`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) does not support random access via an index, you will need to access the elements via iterators (`begin()`, `end()` etc.), e.g.: `auto set_it = team_i.begin();`. `*set_it` will be of type `std::list<std::string>`.

Since [**`std::list<...>`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) also does not support random access via an index, again you will need to access it via iterators, e.g.: `auto list_it = set_it->begin();`. `*list_it` will be of type `std::string`.

This way it is possible to access every set in the vector, every list in each set, and every string in each list (after you have added them to the data structure).

**However** - using iterators with `std::set` and `std::list` is not as convenient as using indexed random access with `std::vector`. `std::vector` has additional benefits (simple and efficient implementation, continous memory block).
If you use `std::vector`s instead of `std::set` and `std::list`, `vek` will be defined as:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> vek;
```

`std::list` being a linked list offers some benefits (like being able to add an element in O(1)). `std::set` guarentees that each value is present once.
But if you don't really need these features, you could make you code simpler (and often more efficient) if you use only `std::vector`s as your containers.

**Note:** if every set will ever contain only 1 list (of strings) you can consider to get rid of 1 level of the hirarchy, I.e. store the lists (or vectors as I suggested) directly as elements of the top-level vector.

---

**UPDATE:**

Since the question was changed, here's a short update:

1. In my answer above, ignore all the mentions of the `std::list`. So when you iterate on the `set::set` the elements are already `std::string`s.
2. The reason the names are not in the order you expect:
   `std::set` keeps the elements sorted, and when you iterate it you will get the elements by that sorting order. See the answer here: [Is the std::set iteration order always ascending according to the C++ specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833938/is-the-stdset-iteration-order-always-ascending-according-to-the-c-specificat). Your set contains `std::string`s and the default sort order for them is alphabetically.
   Using `std::vector` instead of `std::set` like I proposed above, will get you the result you wanted (`std::vector` is not sorted automatically).

If you want to try using only `std::vector`:
Change `vek` to:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>vek;
```

And replace the usage of `insert` (to add an element to the set) with `push_back` to do the same for a vector.

Comment: I edited my question (I'm sorry because of that), could you update your answer?